# Selecting inner object of the list

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following hierarchy within my Project object

- Project

  - Launch

    - Phase

      - Position

and I have them contained as the following :

```
 - Project has List<Launch>
 - Launch has List<Phase>
 - Phase has List<Position>
```

I want to search for the `Phase` object with `Position.Id = 123`. I am expecting only **First object that fulfills the criteria** to be returned i.e. `Phase` object. I have tried doing the following but it returns IEnumerable and cannot be casted directly into Phase object. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
var var_phase = project.Launches
    .Select(l => l.Phases.FirstOrDefault(phase => phase.Positions.Any(p => p.Id == 123)));
```

Comment: You don't specify what do you want as the output of that search operation. Is it projects - the query would be different - or phases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First we want to get `Phases` as a *flat* (not hierarachical) `IEnumerable<Phase>`; we can do it with a help of `SelectMany`:

```
   var allPhases = project
     .Launches
     .SelectMany(launch => launch.Phases);
```

Then we can *filter* these phases with a help of `Where`:

```
   var result = project
     .Launches
     .SelectMany(launch => launch.Phases)
     .Where(phase => phase.Positions.Any(position => position.Id == 123));
```

**Edit:** If you want just *one* `Phase` if it exists or `null` if there are no such phases put `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`:

```
   var result = project
     .Launches
     .SelectMany(launch => launch.Phases)
     .FirstOrDefault(phase => phase.Positions.Any(position => position.Id == 123));
```

Comment: How do I cast it to `Phase`? It still throwing an exception :(

Comment: @Kkt2: what kind of exception do you have? If you want just *one* `Phase` (not a enumeration of them), put `FirstOrDefault` instead of `Where`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Enumerable.SelectMany method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) which flattens the resulting sequences into one sequence.

```
project
    .Launches
    .SelectMany(x => x.Phases)
    .Where(x => x.Positions.Any(p => p.Id == 123));
```

Comment: While this answer is correct, it lacks any explanation.